# How to fetch all data(entries) of a particular folder in firebase

Tags: javascript, json, database, firebase

I was trying to fetch all the (records)entries of a firebase database and put them on a table in HTMl.

[image: Database Screenshot]

I tried doing it like this -

```
function Fetch_data_from_database(to_database,table_id) //function that fetches all the data from the database passed 
{
    firebase.database().ref(to_database).once('value',function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(
            function(ChildSnapshot){
                let name = ChildSnapshot.val().Name;
                let Password = ChildSnapshot.val().Password;
                let User_ID = ChildSnapshot.val().User_ID;
                console.log("gonna print " + name + " " + Password + " " + User_ID );
                add_to_table(table_id,name,Password,User_ID);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

I created a function which intends to read all the (records)entries from a firebase folder , but I am stuck at an error [at line firebase.database().ref ] saying -

[image: Error SS]

I am new to firebase , can anyone please tell me what is wrong ? , also is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried to initialize Realtime Database and add the Realtime Database JS SDK?

Comment: @ChristianPaulAndaya I have included these in the starting - https://xp.io/storage/2eTtOBZ3.png  and also the script Fetch_data_from_user works is imported as type="module" so ig it should work fine

Comment: I am using firebase version 9.10 and this code is for v8 so that is why it is not working , does anyone knows what changes should i make in this function to make it work for v9

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using V9 as described in your comment above, you will want to call `getDatabase()` instead of `firebase.database()`.